# Spray/Scala - Setting timeout on specific request

Tags: scala, timeout, pipeline, spray

I currently have a REST call set up using spray pipeline. If I don't get a response within x number of seconds, I want it to timeout, but only on that particular call. When making a spray client pipeline request, is there a good way to specify a timeout specific to that particular call?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, as of spray-client 1.3.1 there is no way to customise the pipe after it has been created.
However, you can create custom pipes for different types of requests.

It's worth mentioning the fact that the timeouts defined below are the timeouts for the ask() calls, not for the network operations, but I guess this is what you need from your description.

I found the following article very useful in understanding a bit better how the library works behind the scenes: http://kamon.io/teamblog/2014/11/02/understanding-spray-client-timeout-settings/

*Disclaimer*: I haven't actually tried this, but I guess it should work:

```
val timeout1 = Timeout(5 minutes)
val timeout2 = Timeout(1 minutes)

val pipeline1: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive(implicitly[ActorRefFactory],
        implicitly[ExecutionContext], timeout1)

val pipeline2: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive(implicitly[ActorRefFactory],
        implicitly[ExecutionContext], timeout2)
```

and then you obviously use the appropriate pipe for each request